# Efficient method to get all many to many objects from queryset

Tags: python, django, pandas

I have models similar to the below:

```py
class Tag(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

A `Post` can have many `Tags` and `Tags` can be associated with many `Posts`.

What I need is to get a list of all posts along with all the tags associated with each post. I then create a `Pandas DataFrame` from that data. Here is how I am currently doing it:

```py
qs = Post.objects.all().prefetch_related('tags')

tag_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["post_id", "tags"])
for q in qs:
    tag_df = tag_df.append(
        {
            "post_id": q.pk,
            "tags": list(q.tags.all().values_list("text", flat=True)),
        },
        ignore_index=True,
    )

post_df = pd.DataFrame(qs.values("id", "title"))
final_df = post_df.merge(tag_df, left_on="id", right_on="post_id")
```

The result is correct in terms of the data I require. The problem is how incredibly inefficient it is and the number of queries that run even though I'm using `prefetch_related`. It appears that a query is hitting the database for each iteration of the loop.

Is there a better, more efficient way to do this (possibly without loops)? All I need in the end is a dataframe that contains all the posts along with a column which has a list of the tags for each post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `.values_list(..)` you will make an extra query each iteration. So that is not very effective. You can simply use the, already prefetched `Tag` objects, and obtain the `.text` attributes:

```
qs = Post.objects.prefetch_related('tags')

tag_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['post_id', 'tags'])
for q in qs:
    tag_df = tag_df.append(
        {
            'post_id': q.pk,
            'tags': [t.text for t in q.tags.all()],
        },
        ignore_index=True,
    )

post_df = pd.DataFrame(qs.values('id', 'title'))
final_df = post_df.merge(tag_df, left_on='id', right_on='post_id')
```

It might however be more efficient to first make a list of dictionaries, and then load these in a dataframe once:

```
qs = Post.objects.prefetch_related('tags')

data = [
    {'id': q.pk, 'title': q.title, 'tags': [t.text for t in q.tags.all()]}
    for q in qs
]
final_df= pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'title', 'tags'])
```

Note that using `.values(..)` or `.values_list(..)` is not a good idea. Only in certain cases, like making a GROUP BY on a certain value, that is a good idea. Usually it is better to make use of the model objects, since these add an extra layer of logic.